# No sé por qué no me aparece el compareTo

Tags: java

Este es el código que utilizo para comparar, me da el fallo ya que no me deja utilizar la función CompareTo

```
Collections.sort(equiposC, new Comparator<EquipoClasificacion>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(EquipoClasificacion e1, EquipoClasificacion e2) {
                if (e1.getPuntos() != e2.getPuntos()) {
                    return e2.getPuntos().compareTo(e1.getPuntos());
                }
                else {
                    return e2.getGoles().compareTo(e1.getGoles());
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que estas usando tipos primitivos para comparar. Puedes hacer cambiandolo por Integer. Es uno de los viejos dilemas de Java.
Trata de ser mas detallado con las clases al preguntar para que no tengamos que imaginarnos todo el código. Te dejo este ejemplo de código:

```
        public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ArrayList<EquipoClasificacion> equiposC = new ArrayList<>();
            equiposC.add(new EquipoClasificacion());
            equiposC.add(new EquipoClasificacion());
    
            System.out.println(equiposC.toString());
    
            Collections.sort(equiposC, (e1, e2) -> {
                if (e1.getPuntos() != e2.getPuntos()) {
                    //Cuidado con el orden de la comparacion
                    return e1.getPuntos().compareTo(e2.getPuntos());
                } else {
                    return e1.getGoles().compareTo(e2.getGoles());
                }
            });
    
            System.out.println(equiposC.toString());
    
        }
    }
```

Me imagine esta clase de clasificación  de equipos que genera números  aleatorios.

```
public class EquipoClasificacion {
        Random r = new Random();
        Integer puntos = r.nextInt(100);
        Integer goles = r.nextInt(10);
    
        public Integer getPuntos() {
            return puntos;
        }
    
        public Integer getGoles() {
            return goles;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "EquipoClasificacion{" +
                    "puntos=" + puntos +
                    ", goles=" + goles +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías probar con los siguientes cambios:

```
@Override
public int compare( EquipoClasificacion e1, EquipoClasificacion e2 ) {
    return e1.getPuntos() - e2.getPuntos();
}
```

Se espera que el método **compare**, devuelva un número negativo si "A" es mayor que "B", "0" si son iguales y un positivo si "B" es mayor que "A", por lo que simplemente restar los valores, nos da el resultado esperado.
Nota: este mecanismo, solo se debe usar con números pequeños, ya que puede presentar inconsistencias, por ejemplo, si tuviésemos que comparar los números **2000000000** y **-2100000000**, la diferencia entre ambos, está más allá de lo que la clase puede manejar, generando un error.